# Torch for camera '0' is not available due to an existing camera user [XAMARIN.FORM]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, zxing, flashlight

i have a trouble that can't resolve.
I'm doing an Android Xamarin form application that use camera (like a scanner) to capture QR Code (for this i use Zxing NuGet Package).
The problem is occured when i'm trying to Turn On the camera Flash (for this i use Xamarin.Exentials) but obviously the code return an Exception ("CAMERA_IN_USE(4): setTorchMode:1732: Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user").

Note: The button of flash activator is an icon in the toolbar -> "ToolbarItems", and is not the button already integrated in the Zxing Package.

I tried a lot of web solution but nothing work, i'm posting the code below. THANKS!

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var zxing = new ZXingScannerView
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            AutomationId = "zxingScannerView",
            IsTorchOn = false,
            IsScanning=true,
            IsAnalyzing=true,
            Options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions()
            {
                //IMPORTANT: this is used for stretch camera problem! //(interface: ZXingHelper.cs, file: ZxingHelper.cs)
                PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() { ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE },
                CameraResolutionSelector = DependencyService.Get<IZXingHelper>().SelectLowestResolutionMatchingDisplayAspectRatio
            }
        };

        zxing.OnScanResult += (result) =>
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

                // Stop analysis and scanning until we navigate away so we don't keep reading barcodes
                zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;
                zxing.IsScanning = false;

                // Show an alert
                await DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");

                //Update QR saved List
                updateDataBase(result.Text);

                //Do Action After Update Scanner
                if (result.Text.StartsWith("http://") || result.Text.StartsWith("https://") || result.Text.StartsWith("www."))
                {
                    QRUrlModel qRUrlModel = new QRUrlModel();
                    qRUrlModel.url = result.Text;
                    await Xamarin.Essentials.Browser.OpenAsync(qRUrlModel.url, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
                }
                else
                {
                    //await Navigation.PushAsync(new BookmarkPage());
                }

            });

        var overlay = new ZXingDefaultOverlay
        {
            TopText = "Hold your phone up to the barcode",
            BottomText = "Scanning will happen automatically",
            //ShowFlashButton = true,
            AutomationId = "zxingDefaultOverlay",
        };

        overlay.FlashButtonClicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            zxing.IsTorchOn = !zxing.IsTorchOn;
        };

        var Grid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };
        Grid.Children.Add(zxing);
        Grid.Children.Add(overlay);
        Content = Grid;
    }


private async void BtnFash_ToolbarItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try
        {
            // Turn On Flashlight  
            await Flashlight.TurnOnAsync();
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Attention", fnsEx.Message, "OK");
        }
        catch (PermissionException pEx)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Attention", pEx.Message, "OK");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Attention", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
```

}

Comment: I think this is working as expected. Essentials can't access the flash because whenever the camera is open, access to the torch is locked out so only the camera can access it. Is there any reason you can't use the torch button that ZXing provides?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The reason is because i want to use the toolbaritem button to activate the flash, because it is prettier! If i try to active the zxing button it appear in the middle of the scanner screen and it is not good to view. Now i try to stop the camera when i use the flash button. I haven't any other idea :(

Comment: You could possibly use a custom overlay to move the scan button. The repo and Google have samples on how you might achieve that.